# GCE: How do you get the load balancer(s) to refuse excessive traffic?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I'm trying to run third-party server software on GCE (Compute Engine). It talks HTTP and/or HTTPS, runs in one Managed Instance Group and gets traffic from Appengine.

This particular program behaves very badly if it gets too many requests per instance. Therefore I want the the load balancer to refuse requests if the load is too great. But I can't get any of the ones I have tested to behave this way. Whatever "Balancing Mode" I set, it seems like it always distributes the requests to the healthy instances in my group. This leads to too many requests per instance under peak (before auto-scaling kicks in) and means that all requests fail.

Is there a way to get any of the load balancers to refuse excessive traffic? For example return an HTTP error right away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a functionnality that the load balancer can't do, but you may be able to find what you are looking in cloud armor: https://cloud.google.com/armor/

Some of the options are still in Beta/Alpha and is still going to evoluate.

If that still not good enough you won't have a choice and should create a tcp LB to direct traffic to something else like a HAproxy to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at Apigee actually. The spike arrest policy handles your use case.
https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/spike-arrest-policy

If you are more price sensitive, look at cloud endpoints throttling.
https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/rate-limiting